# A lot of circles intersect in 1 point

Tags: geometry

A circle has been built on each side of a 11-angled polygon(it may be not convex), where the side is the diameter of the circle. How can I prove that if all of these circles have an intersection point, the intersection point will coincide with one of the vertexes of the given polygon?

Comment: The circle with diameter $AB$ is the locus of points $P$ such that $\widehat{APB}$ is a right angle. If all those circle have a common point, such a point "sees" every side of the given 11-agon under a right angle.

Comment: And what does this fact about seeing the side under a right angle give us?

Comment: Think about it. Is there such point for a regular $11$-agon?

Comment: It does not, of course

Comment: Then consider my extended hint below: $4$ consecutive vertices distinct from $P$ make a whole "turn" around $P$, but there are $11$ vertices, and $11$ is not a multiple of $4$, so $P$ has to be one of the $11$ vertices.

Answer (score 0):

The circle with diameter $AB$ is the locus of points P such that $\widehat{APB}$ is a right angle. If all those circle have a common point, such a point "sees" every side of the given 11-agon under a right angle, or 
is an endpoint of such a side.

Extended hint:
[image]

Is it possible that such a path closes in $11$ steps withouth going through $P$, since $4\nmid 11$?